# Python script to translate via google translate

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, google-translate

I'm trying to learn python, so I decided to write a script that could translate something using google translate. Till now I wrote this:

```
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import urllib

data = {'sl':'en','tl':'it','text':'word'} 
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.translate.google.com', urllib.urlencode(data))

request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11')
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
feeddata = opener.open(request).read()
#print feeddata
soup = BeautifulSoup(feeddata)
print soup.find('span', id="result_box")
print request.get_method()
```

And now I'm stuck. I can't see any bugs in it, but it still doesn't work (by that I mean that the script will run, but it wont translate the word).

Does anyone know how to fix it?
(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: What errors do you get if any?

Comment: As I said, I don't get any errors, everything seem to work, but in the ind i get:

    <span id="result_box" class="short_text"></span>

There should be 'something' in this span tag.

Comment: in the end you get what? you asking to print out method. What are you aiming to return?

Comment: Perhaps because Google Translate has [an API you should use](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/overview.html) if you want to programmatically translate text?

Comment: The translation should show up in this span tag. I was going to expose it using BeautifulSoup, but now I'm trying to get any translation.

Comment: check this modern tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google translate is meant to be used with a `GET` request and not a `POST` request. However, `urrllib2` will automatically submit a `POST` if you add any data to your request.

The solution is to construct the url with a querystring so you will be submitting a `GET`.
You'll need to alter the `request = urllib2.Request('http://www.translate.google.com', urllib.urlencode(data))` line of your code.

Here goes:

```
querystring = urllib.urlencode(data)
request = urllib2.Request('http://www.translate.google.com' + '?' + querystring )
```

And you will get the following output:

```
<span id="result_box" class="short_text">
    <span title="word" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#ebeff9'" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff'">
        parola
    </span>
</span>
```

*By the way, you're kinda breaking Google's terms of service; look into them if you're doing more than hacking a little script for training.*

### Using `requests`

I strongly advise you to stay away from urllib if possible, and use the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) library, which will allow you to efficiently use `HTTP` with Python.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :)
And I didn't realize that it was against google's terms of service, just wanted to learn something, and it seemd quite interesting.
I'll definitly check this requests library, thanks again :)

Comment: Glad I helped. Regarding the terms, consider the fact that google translate is now a paid service: http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html

Answer (score 10):

I made this script if you want to check it:
https://github.com/mouuff/Google-Translate-API
: )

Comment: You can add another hack to your code to fake the user agent in every request

from fake_useragent import UserAgent
ua = UserAgent()
def getuseragent():
    while True:
        try:
            return {'User-Agent': ua.random.encode()}
        except:
            pass

Comment: @Arnaud-Aliès do you happen to know the requests limit for translate.google.com? I was using your module and in less than 30min I received `HTTP Status code 429: too many requests.` Most of the online answers talk about request limits for the Translate API but I was wondering if you had that data for Python's `requests` module

Answer (score 5):

Yes their documentation is not so easy to uncover.

### Here's what you do:

1. **In the Google Cloud Platform Console**:

   1.1 [Go to the Projects page and select or create a new project](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en)

   1.2 [Enable billing for your project](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293499?authuser=1#enable-billing)

   1.3 [Enable the Cloud Translation API](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158841?hl=en)

   1.4 [Create a new API key in your project](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en), make sure to restrict usage by IP or other means available there.

---

2. **In the machine where you want to run the client**:

   > pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

---

3. Then you can write this to send translation requests and receive responses:

**Here's the code**:

```
import json
from apiclient.discovery import build

query='this is a test to translate english to spanish'
target_language = 'es'

service = build('translate','v2',developerKey='INSERT_YOUR_APP_API_KEY_HERE')

collection = service.translations()

request = collection.list(q=query, target=target_language)

response = request.execute()

response_json = json.dumps(response)

ascii_translation = ((response['translations'][0])['translatedText']).encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')

utf_translation = ((response['translations'][0])['translatedText']).encode('utf-8')

print response
print ascii_translation
print utf_translation
```