# how to translate word with google translator?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm making simple script that will translate words from English to Russian language using requests and BeatifulSoup, the problem is that the result box is empty where should be translated word/ I'm not sure if i should use GET or POST method. This is what I've tried

```
with open('File.csv', 'r') as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file)

    for line in csv_reader:
        if line[1] == '':

            url = 'https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/{}'.format(line[0])
            r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

            translate = soup.find('span', id='result_box')
            for word in translate:
                print(word.find('span', class_=''))
```

Comment: Why not use [Google API](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way of using google translation by Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22587001/best-way-of-using-google-translation-by-python)

Comment: You can't do it like this, because in `r` variable there is no translation yet, google translator shows translation dynamically. So BS4 will never get it. Better to use googletrans package or you can try to parse it with Selenium if you can't use API.

Comment: you may want to try this tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to consider using the [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) package.

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
text = translator.translate('text', src='en', dest='ru')
print(text.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

The question was asked two years ago so I'll post an answer or rather a suggestion here. You may want to try the [deep_translator](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep_translator) package if it matches your needs.

```
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator

translated = GoogleTranslator(source='auto', target='ru').translate(text='happy coding')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.formatter import HTMLFormatter
from googletrans import Translator
import requests

translator = Translator()
```

see this complete googletrans code over here:

https://neculaifantanaru.com/en/python-code-text-google-translate-website-translation-beautifulsoup-library.html

Answer (score 0):

this is what i did, if you have library problem please handle it in the following way

```
cmd: pip3 uninstall googletrans
cmd: pip3 install googletrans==3.1.0a0
```

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

text = "How to convert some text to multiple languages"
destination_language = {
    "spanish": "es",
    "chinese": "zh-CN",
    "vietnamese": "vi",
    "korean": "ko",
    "japanese": "ja",
    "french": "fr",
}

for key, value in destination_language.items():
    trans = translator.translate(text, dest=value).text
    print(trans)
```