# How to translate entire .txt file using Google Translate API in Python?

Tags: python, google-api, translate

I am trying to translate an entire `.txt` file using Google Translate API in Python.

The default code is:

```
print(service.translations().list(source='zh',
                                  target='en',
                                  q=['上海熙缘节能环保科技服务有限公司',
                                     '广东宏德科技物业有限公司']).execute())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How can I modify this code so it can translate a .txt file?

Comment: Are you asking how to read text from a file?

Comment: Yes but with Chinese characters so the file is in UTF or Unicode.  The default decoder is in cp1252

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python script to translate via google translate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404628/python-script-to-translate-via-google-translate)

Answer (score 0):

The simple and efficient solution from my own perspective without knowing the complex details and I assume the parameter `q` is the sequence of sentences/words that you want to translate will be:

```
print(service.translations().list( source='zh', target='en', q= (line.rstrip() for line in open('file.txt') ).execute())
```

I see your expression to be really unpythonic, you nest a lot of expressions into one single line.

Comment: Thanks direprobs, using what Google provided.  Now that I've done that I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 50: character maps to <undefined> error.  Google Translate's API is using cp1252 but my Chinese text has to be saved in Unicode to keep their values, otherwise they disappear.

Comment: Here is a piece of the code Google uses as a Decoder       class IncrementalDecoder(codecs.IncrementalDecoder):
    def decode(self, input, final=False):
        return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]

class StreamWriter(Codec,codecs.StreamWriter):
    pass

class StreamReader(Codec,codecs.StreamReader):
    pass

### encodings module API

def getregentry():
    return codecs.CodecInfo(
        name='cp1252',
        encode=Codec().encode,

Comment: @shj997 Refer to this page from Python Documentation: [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).